# Disable Telerik MVC Grid Validation

Tags: javascript, asp.net-mvc, telerik, telerik-grid, telerik-mvc

I have a telerik grid that is using a EditorTemplate:

Editor:

`@ModelType Date

 @Html.Telerik.DatePicker.Name(ViewData.TemplateInfo.GetFullHtmlFieldName(String.Empty)).Value(Model)`

In my viewModel:

`UIHint("Date")

DisplayFormat(ApplyFormatInEditMode:=True, DataFormatString:="{0:dd-MM-yyyy}")

Public Property data As Date`

I can't get the client side validations to work **so i decided to disable them**.
I added in the webconfig (views and app)

`add key="ClientValidationEnabled" value="false" 

add key="UnobtrusiveJavaScriptEnabled" value="false"`

But it still tries to validate the field. I suppose it's some property in the grid.. 
How can i disable the validations?

Thks.

EDIT:

I tested this in a simple form and both ClientValidationEnabled and UnobtrusiveJavaScriptEnabled are false. So the problem should be in the telerik Grid, it ignores those keys and still makes its validations. How do i disable the validation in the grid?

Answer (score 0):

Its possible that your page is being cached. Try a Ctrl + F5 and/or delete your cache and try again.

```
<configuration>
<appSettings>
<add key="ClientValidationEnabled" value="false"/> 
<add key="UnobtrusiveJavaScriptEnabled" value="false"/> 
</appSettings>
```

I just tried it (with both false) and it works fine.

Comment: you can set enable client validation in your View too.  @{ Html.EnableClientValidation(false); }

Comment: Thks for the answer Yasser, but i tried that already and it didn't solved it. the input is inside a EditorTemplate, can this be related to the problem?